# Best practice to locate "attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Tags: python, exception, python-import, python-3.7, relative-import

I would like to narrow the common error `"attempted relative import beyond top-level package"` down by including the exception-handling in the imports already.

In my Django tests in `DjangoProject/tests.py` I wrote the imports relative to itself (`tests.py`).
The default `unittests.py` which executes each testfile is located in the root-folder which also includes the DjangoProject-folder.

As I was getting the error `attempted relative import beyond top-level package` the moment I added the 
`DjangoProject/tests.py` to my Unit-Tests adnd it was clear it came from the imports. With a try/except I was able to write a slightly clearer error so I'm not in the need of guessing around why and which file caused the error.

Now my code looks like this:

```
try:
    from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
    import json
    from django.conf import settings
    from viewsfunctions import *
    from .. import PoM
    import unittest
except Exception as importex:
    print("Error in the tests.py-imports: "+str(importex))
```

And it threw first of all the message:

```
"No module named 'viewsfunctions'"
```

which makes sense and is helpful as `viewsfunctions` is a module inside `DjangoProject`. I replaced the line with: `from DjangoProject.viewsfunctions import *`

The next error is:

```
Error in the Imports: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

And this is exactly my problem. This could be *anything*. By just pdbing around I could track it down to `from .. import PoM` (as the module `PoM` is relative to `tests.py` in the top-folder, but relative to the executing `unittests.py` in the same folder)

In this case with just a few imports it's relatively fast to narrow it down, but is there any way to write a better exception message or deliver somehow more information in which of the import-lines the error actually happened?

Comment: What command line are you using to run the tests?

Answer (score 0):

If you would simply *not* catch the exception, you'd get a very useful traceback:

```
>>> from .. import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/deceze/...", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

The problem is that you're catching the exception and are only printing the most minimal error message possible. If you do want to catch the exception for some reason yet still get a complete error message, the easiest way would be to use the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html):

```
import logging

try:
    ...
except:
    logging.exception('Error fooing the bar')
```

This will produce your custom error message *followed by a complete stack trace*.

To get even more manual, use the [`traceback` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#module-traceback):

```
import traceback

try:
    ...
except:
    print('Error fooing the bar')
    traceback.print_exc()
```

With other functions in `traceback` you can get even more granular and print or retrieve messages from an exception as granular as you like.

Comment: If I don't catch the exception I get an extra-vague `*** ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` without any information at all

Comment: `python3.7 unittests.py `, executed from where it is (top-level)

Comment: And the error is occurring in `unittest.py` directly, or in one of the tests which it discovers and imports from elsewhere? What if you put only "`from .. import foo`" into a .py file as the only thing and run that directly?